# Enable Contacts/Gmail scopes for Google Apps connection in Auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, google-contacts-api, auth0

I'm trying to set up authentication for a webapp using Auth0 and a Google Enterprise connection.
The applications needs to be able to access the user's *profile*, *contacts*, and *gmail*.

When I tried this using a **Social** connection in Auth0, I configured it to ask for *Contacts* and *Gmail* permissions. The consent then shows up as expected:
[Configuration using Social Google Connection in Auth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEAgg.png)

But when I try the same thing using an **Enterprise** Connection in Auth0, the *Contacts* and *Gmail* permissions are not available. And so, the consent screen won't ask for them either:
[Configuration using Enterprise Google Connection in Auth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh92S.png)

What am I missing here? How do I setup authentication so that it

- only allows in users from my Google Apps directory,
- but also: requests the correct permissions for those users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`connection_scopes`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/sending-authentication-parameters#connection_scopes-object-) in Lock or `connection_scope` in Auth0JS or the /authorize call to pass on any scopes you want to request to the Identity Provider.